# Why can't I change the width in a Sharepoint list gallery view with Json?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I'm fairly new to using JSON and I'm trying to create a Gallery view to use with dynamic filtering.  I have the view working the way I want, but I can't get the width and height of the 'card' to be what I want.

The width of my card is fine, but the height is too tall.  If I change the height in the JSON, the width of the card get smaller.

In the image you can see all of the space below the text that I want to get rid of.

[image]

Here's my JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": "150",
  "width": "600",
  "hideSelection": false,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
      "display": "flex",
      "align-items": "stretch",
      "margin-bottom": "16px",
      "flex-grow": "1",
      "justify-content": "space-around",
      "padding": "5px"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "width": "100%",
          "height": "100%",
          "flex-wrap": "wrap",
          "display": "flex",
          "box-sizing": "border-box",
          "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
          "border-radius": "2px"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLighterAlt"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "text-align": "left"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {
                  "color": "#333333",
                  "font-size": "16px",
                  "font-weight": "600",
                  "margin-bottom": "5px"
                },
                "txtContent": "[$Title]"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help or tips are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding width & height properties inside `style` like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": false,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
      "display": "flex",
      "height": "150",
      "width": "600",
      "align-items": "stretch",
      "margin-bottom": "16px",
      "flex-grow": "1",
      "justify-content": "space-around",
      "padding": "5px"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "width": "100%",
          "height": "100%",
          "flex-wrap": "wrap",
          "display": "flex",
          "box-sizing": "border-box",
          "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
          "border-radius": "2px"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLighterAlt"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "text-align": "left"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {
                  "color": "#333333",
                  "font-size": "16px",
                  "font-weight": "600",
                  "margin-bottom": "5px"
                },
                "txtContent": "[$Title]"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this didn't completely solve the issue.  It did fix the height, but it made the width of the cards less and leaves a large space when it wraps (see image).  Changing the width and height doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Add your Width and Height without the quotes:

```
"height": 150,
"width": 600,
```